# How to populate HTML table with JSON data via jQuery AJAX call

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

I need to populate a table with JSON data via a jQuery AJAX call,

The format of the JSON data:

```
{"message":[
              {"name":"A","value":"7%"},
              {"name":"B","value":"3%"}
           ]}
```

Can anyone help to find out what's wrong with this AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
         type : "GET",
         url : "",
         dataType : "json",
         success : function(data) {
            var Options = '';
            $.each($(data.message), function() {                        
                Options +='<li'+this.name+':'+this.value+'</li>';  
            });

            $("#list1").append(Options);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure waht exactly is your problem. But I found something wrong in formatting. Your 'li' tag is not opened correctly.

```
Options +='<li'+this.name+':'+this.value+'</li>';
```

Change it to,

```
Options +='<li>'+this.name+':'+this.value+'</li>';
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

```js
"fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
    console.log(aData[1]);
    if (aData[1] == "Imported")
    {
        // $('td').css('background-color', '#FBE9E7');
        $(nRow).find('td:eq(1)').html('<span class="label label-success">'+aData[1]+'</span>');
    } else if (aData[1] == "Inactive") {
        $(nRow).find('td:eq(1)').html('<span class="label label-danger">'+aData[1]+'</span>');
    } else if(aData[1] == "Exported") {
        $(nRow).find('td:eq(1)').html('<span class="label label-primary">'+aData[1]+'</span>');
    }else{
        $(nRow).find('td:eq(1)').html('<span class="label label-default">'+aData[1]+'</span>');
        // $.addClass('label label-default');
    }

},
```

[image]